# How do you call a field from a record type?

Tags: f#

If I have a type like so:

```
type Cats = 
    { Breed = string
      Color = string
      Alive = bool }
```

And I map data to it:

```
let mapdata = 
    Catfile.GetSample().Rows
    |> Seq.map (fun row -> 
    { Breed = row.breed
      Color = row.color
      Alive = row.status }
```

How do I call "Breed" or "Color" from that record?
My thinking, is that it would be something like:

```
Cats.Breed or Cats.Color
```

Is this true?

When I call the field within a record I mean to call a sequence of all the data mapped to that field.

**Edited:**

I want to be able to filter data from another csv based on the results from above, without having to run the whole function of "mapdata" again. 
So I would like to be able to isolate the results from "Breed" by doing something like: `Cats.Breed` to call all the values in that field and filter different data based on whether its in `Cats.Breed`.

A function like:

```
let similarvalues = Seq.Contains (OtherData) Cats.Breed
```

Comment: Does `mapdata |> Seq.map (fun c -> c.Breed)` give you what you want? If not, can you give an example of the shape of the data that you want to extract?

Comment: I added some explanation

Comment: I am familiar with r, sql, excel, and know a little bit of python. My bad I mean mapdata is a value and not a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the properties of a record type by using the `.` operator on the instance of the record, such as `cat.Breed`.  Since you're working with collections of `Cat` record types, you'll need to use a higher order function over that sequence to apply the `.` operator to each instance and access its properties.  We'll use your example of filtering CSV files containing cats to demonstrate how this works.

For cats in the sequence generated from the first CSV file, you'll need to use a function like `Seq.exists` to check the `Breed` property of each cat against the row you're on in the second CSV file.  That might look something like this:

```
type Cat = 
    { Breed: string
      Color: string
      Alive: bool 
    }

// Example CSV data type
type Row = 
    { Breed: string
      Color: string
      Status: bool 
    }

let csvData = 
    // Load rows from CSV1
    [{Breed = "fun"; Color = "lovely"; Status = true}]
    |> Seq.map (fun row -> 
        { Breed = row.Breed
          Color = row.Color
          Alive = row.Status })

// Check for matching data in CSV2
let similarData =
    // Load rows from CSV2
    [{Breed = "grumpy"; Color = "muddy"; Status = true}]
    |> Seq.filter (fun row -> csvData |> Seq.exists (fun cat -> cat.Breed = row.Breed))
```

As you can see, when binding `similarData`, we use the `Seq.filter` function over each row in the second CSV file to find only the rows where a cat with the same breed exists in the sequence generate from the first CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

A record is a type. You would have to iterate over the results of your 'mapdata' function to access those properties, similar to the way your called Seq.map in the code you provided.